# Using bash from cmake in azure pipelines tries to invoke WSL, but invoking from pipeline code does not

Tags: windows, cmake, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an `execute_process(COMMAND bash script.sh)` task in my CMakeLists.txt file which is being built on azure pipelines using the following pipline task:

```
- bash: |
    cmake .
```

Recently this has stopped working and throws the error "Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions".

If I run the command using the following yaml in my `azure-pipelines.yaml` It works fine and does not throw any error.

```
- bash:
    ./script.sh
```

Why does invoking the same script from cmake try to invoke WSL and how can i stop this from happening so it just runs the script?

The same script runs fine in both linux and mac pipeline stages, so i would like it to be consistent with windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I used for this issue was to create a windows batch file with the same commands and then just call that if cmake is being run from windows.

```
if(MSVC)
    execute_process ( COMMAND script.bat)
else()
    execute_process ( COMMAND bash script.sh)
endif()
```

The azure pipeline task then works OK:

```
- bash: |
    cmake .
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the exact same issue. And i found this command `execute_process(COMMAND powershell bash script.sh)` works on windows agent.

If you want to make it consistent with windows. You can add below additional line in your CMakeLists.txt file. This additional line will only works on windows.

```
execute_process(COMMAND bash script.sh)
execute_process(COMMAND powershell bash script.sh) #works on windows
```

Comment: The issue with this is that it breaks cross compatibility of the cmake script (where powershell does not exist on mac/linux)

My workaround was to make a `.bat` script and execute that instead.

Comment: @ChrisBamford Using .bat script is indeed a better workaround. Could you share your solution and accept it as answer?